# How does PC install drivers and device info?

Tags: bluetooth, usb-device, device-characteristics

Can someone please explain how a PC knows all the info of a device as soon as you plug it in? How can I add this functionality to a bluetooth or USB device?

Comment: USB uses the VID (vendor ID) and PID (peripheral? ID) to look up what the part is against a list of drivers present on the system.  If something matches, the driver will be loaded.  If nothing matches, it'll ask you for a driver.  Additionally, many devices use standard USB classes which do not require additional drivers (e.g. USB mice/keyboards use the USB HID class).

Comment: The USB controller or IC you're using probably has this explained in its documentation.

Comment: It seems to me that if you know enough to make a bluetooth or USB device you should know the answer to this question since it's integral and trivial. If you're trying to build something you might be getting ahead of yourself and worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! 1. I know that the computer or the user can just search the internet for drivers and then download them, but I'm confused as to how they get information about the device. 2. I don't know how to make a USB or bluetooth device. I'm just wondering how.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-inf-files

Answer (score 1):

After a USB device is plugged in, host performs device "enumeration". During enumeration process the device supplies the host with "device descriptors". Part of device descriptor informs the host about **formal device class**, and the OS loads the corresponding standard driver. If the device describes itself as proprietary "user-defined", the system will ask for proprietary deriver. If no driver with matching VID and PID (Vendor ID and Product ID) is found, the device will get "yellow mark" in Device Manager and will be non-functional. Having device descriptor(s) and responding to initial control commands from USB host is mandatory for all USB devices.